# Failed to resolve compile "org.java-websocket:java-websocket:1.3.2"

Tags: android, gradle, java-websocket

I am developing chat application based on a demo from [github](https://github.com/NaikSoftware/stomp-protocol-example-server). They used java-webocket:1.3.2, I was using java-websocket:1.3.1 but I got error because in 1.3.1 there is no setSocket() method. Then I changed in the gradle my version and suddenly I got this error

> Failed to resolve compile "org.java-websocket:java-websocket:1.3.2"

I tried to find jar of this library but I could not find. I do not know why this is happening I am stuck with this error for 2 hours now, my internet is working fine but I cannot add java-websocket:1.3.2 to my dependencies but its working fine when I change back to 1.3.1

Answer (score 2, accepted):

please add   `maven { url 'http://clojars.org/repo' }` into your build.gradle that under the project then it will work.

Answer (score 1):

did you add their maven repository to your build?
central only carries that artifact up to 1.3.0 (see [link](http://search.maven.org/#search%7Cga%7C1%7Cg%3A%22org.java-websocket%22))
as per [their website](https://github.com/TooTallNate/Java-WebSocket), you need to add their repo:

```
maven { url "http://clojars.org/repo" }
```

to your build.gradle